# Assigning a correct value with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a little quiz that asks when was the great depression. There are 4 divs that contain a decade, with 1920 being the correct answer (3rd div). In my jQuery I have put that any variable that has a value of 1920 = 'correct_answer' and that when it is clicked on there will be a message that reads 'correct'. Any other answer will alert 'wrong'. Why isn't this working?

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head> 
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hello.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p class="question"> When was the Great Depression? </p>
        <div class="answer" value="1940" id="answer_1"> 1940's </div>
        <div class="answer" value="1980" id="answer_2"> 1980's </div>
        <div class="answer" value="1960" id="answer_3"> 1960's </div>
        <div class="answer" value="1920" id="answer_4"> 1920's </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            grade();
        })
            function grade() {
                var correct_answer = 1920;

                if($('.answer').attr('value') == correct_answer) {
                    $(this).click(function() {
                        alert('Correct');
                    }) else {
                        alert('Wrong');
                    }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Java -- Java tag removed.

Comment: You're calling your grade function when the page loads, not when the user interacts with an element. Also, `$('.answer').attr('value')` will only select the first element with the answer class.

Comment: You should assign the click listener before the conditional. The way you coded it, the click listener will only be assigned if the answer is correct, but there will never be a click if the event listener hasn't been setup.

Answer (score 3):

Changing your HTML a bit to accommodate [**data-attributes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

```
    <div class="answer" data-value="1940" id="answer_1"> 1940's </div>
    <div class="answer" data-value="1980" id="answer_2"> 1980's </div>
    <div class="answer" data-value="1960" id="answer_3"> 1960's </div>
    <div class="answer" data-value="1920" id="answer_4"> 1920's </div>
```

Bind a [**.click()**](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event to your elements.

```
$(function(){
    var correctAnswer = "1920";
    $(".answer").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var currentVal = $this.data("value");

        if (currentVal === correctAnswer) {
            //your logic goes here
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong order

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var correct_answer = 1920;
    $(".answer").on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == correct_answer) {
            alert('correct');
        } else {
            alert('Wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bjg0kgLp/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in thi way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.answer').on('click',function(){
      var selectedAnswer = $(this).attr('value')
      //now you can make the needed check here
   })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Flip the IF statement :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  grade();
})

function grade() {
    var correct_answer = 1920;
    $('.answer').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('value') == correct_answer) {
          alert('Correct');
        } else {
          alert('Wrong');
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="hello.css">
</head>

<body>
  <p class="question">When was the Great Depression?</p>
  <div class="answer" value="1940" id="answer_1">1940's</div>
  <div class="answer" value="1980" id="answer_2">1980's</div>
  <div class="answer" value="1960" id="answer_3">1960's</div>
  <div class="answer" value="1920" id="answer_4">1920's</div>

</body>

</html>
```